# Error when trying to use eloquent relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get this problem fixed for hours now and I just don't get what I am doing wrong.

I want to get all entries of my tables where my id of posts equals the id of tables bewerbungens.

So I get all applications of every user existing with the corresponding title of the post the user applied to.

I asked a question here before and got resources to add relationships, which I did, as seen here:

Bewerbungen Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'bewerber_email',
    'Stellenanzeigen_ID',
    'is_Accepted',
    'accept_Date',
    'is_Canceled',
    'cancel_Date',
    'is_Received',
    'receive_Date',
    'is_Canceled_Bewerber',
    'cancel_Date_Bewerber',
    'lebenslauf_File',
    'zeugnis_File',
    'anschreiben_File',
    'weitere_Doks',
];

public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Post', 'Stellenanzeigen_ID', 'Bewerbung_ID');
}
```

and here in my Post model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'titel',
        'startdate',
        'enddate',
        'beschreibung',
        'standort',
        'type_name',
        'abteilung_name',
        'kontakt',
        'isActive',
        'lebenslauf',
        'zeugnisse',
        'anschreiben',
        'weitere_Doks',
        'is_Permitted',
        'job_start',
    ];

    public function bewerbungen() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bewerbungen::class);
    }
```

Here is my Controller code where I try to get the entries:

```
   $dummy = Post::with('Bewerbungen.post')->get();
```

But I get the error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'portal.bewerbungen_post' doesn't exist (SQL: select `bewerbungens`.*, `bewerbungen_post`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `bewerbungen_post`.`bewerbungen_id` as `pivot_bewerbungen_id` from `bewerbungens` inner join `bewerbungen_post` on `bewerbungens`.`id` = `bewerbungen_post`.`bewerbungen_id` where `bewerbungen_post`.`post_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4))

I also tried this instead:

```
    $dummy = Post::where('id', 'Stellenanzeigen_ID')->get();
```

But it just returns an empty set.

How can I fix this?

Edit: Post Model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'titel',
        'startdate',
        'enddate',
        'beschreibung',
        'standort',
        'type_name',
        'abteilung_name',
        'kontakt',
        'isActive',
        'lebenslauf',
        'zeugnisse',
        'anschreiben',
        'weitere_Doks',
        'is_Permitted',
        'job_start',
    ];

    public function location() {
        return $this->hasOne(Standort::class);
    }

    public function job_type() {
        return $this->hasOne(Jobtypes::class);
    }

    public function bewerbungen(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bewerbungen::class, 'bewerbungens');
    }
```

I had the bewerbungen() method as suggested in the comment, I just played around with it so it looks different, but it is currently not in use since it didn't work

Comment: Can you check the SQL with,  `$dummy = Post::with('Bewerbungen.post')->toSql();` It will give you the SQL query which you can run directly into the database tool.

Comment: @SuryapalRao I get this then: "select * from `posts` where `Bewerbungen`.`post` is null"

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Error said that there's no `bewerbungen_post` table, since you use `belongsToMany` with only one argument. As mentioned [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure), if your relationship's intermediate table name is different with the Laravel Behavior, then add the relationship's intermediate table name to the second argument, or Laravel will join the two table for the relation table's name. For example:

```
public function bewerbungen() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Bewerbungen::class, 'bewerbungen_post');
}
```

I've checked your previous question, and I think that the `Post` model joined directly to the `Bewerbungen` model, so the relation in the `Post` Model should looks like this:

```
public function bewerbungens(): HasMany
{
    // It's mean that `Post` has many `Bewerbungen` where `Stellenanzeigen_ID` = `posts.id`
    return $this->hasMany(Bewerbungen::class, 'Stellenanzeigen_ID', 'id'); 
}
```

And in the Bewerbungen model:

```
public function post(): BelongsTo
{
    // It's mean that `Bewerbungen` owned by Post as `Stellenanzeigen_ID` = `posts.id`
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'Stellenanzeigen_ID', 'id');
}
```

If you want to get `Post` with all `Bewerbungen` owned by `Posts`:

```
// You will get All Post with all Bewerbungen each Post
$posts = Post::with('bewerbungens')->get();
```

Vice versa:

```
// You will All Bewerbungen and One Post for every Bewerbungen
$bewerbungen = Bewerbungen::with('post')->get();
```

All details about relationship could be found in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer! I will try it out now :) just one question, is it fine if I delete the tables from the database, change the relations and then rerun the migrations? or do I need completely new migration files?

Comment: sadly I get this error message: Call to undefined relationship [bewerbungens] on model [App\Models\Post] when trying $posts = Post::with('bewerbungens')->get();

Comment: @newbie Hmm...that's weird. The relation should created when you create a method and return a relationship classes. How about `Bewerbungen` Model ? Is it error just like the `Post` model ? Could you please show me your full model's code ?

Comment: sorry was asleep :D the Bewerbungen works fine, I got it to work now. I didn't fully understand why yesterday night, hence I went to sleep and now I am just starting up phpstorm :D I will update the post with the full model!

Comment: @newbie I think what you need in `Post` model is `hasMany`, not `belongsToMany`, isn't it ? (Just like my second code, not the first one). Because, relation between your `Post` and `Bewerbungen` is, `Post.id` = `Bewerbungen.Stellenanzeigen_ID` right ? If so, then it means Post will has many Bewerbungen, and Bewerbungen will only belongs to one Post.

Comment: Yeah you are totally correct! From my logical thinking it is absolutely right the way you wrote it in your first answer, but for some reason I get the error when I did it like you first wrote. I then tinkered around a bit and just kept getting errors so I solved it in another way

Comment: I don't know for sure but I had every combination possible for this relationship :D The second example you wrote with hasMany is the one making the most sense since it is, as you said, one Post has many Bewerbungen, but a Bewerbung belongs to one post. I Assume it is some error with this: 
  `return $this->hasMany(Bewerbungen::class, 'Stellenanzeigen_ID', 'id')´

But I am very uncertain